Using XAML code ControlTemplate.Triggers doesn't trigger on the Password.Length of PasswordBox
I am trying to apply password-hint on a PasswordBox using XAML, it applied perfectly but not hiding the password-hint when password is typed in.
Password-hint not hiding in the picture:

My tried XAML style resource for PasswordBox :
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PasswordStyle" TargetType="PasswordBox" >
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PasswordBox">
                    <Border MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Margin="8">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Name="PART_TempText" Text="Enter Password" Foreground="#807C7C"
Visibility="Collapsed" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="8" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Password.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_TempText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Password.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_TempText" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>

And the `PasswordBox` XAML code:
 <PasswordBox Grid.Row="6" x:Name="txtPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" KeyUp="txtPassword_KeyUp"
             Style="{StaticResource PasswordStyle}" />

I want to hide the password-hint when user start typing in the `PasswordBox` using XAML.
You any help related to XAML will be appreciated!
Edited I want to trigger DataTrigger of PasswordBox using Password.Length.
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Password.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
        <Setter TargetName="PART_TempText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Password.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
        <Setter TargetName="PART_TempText" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>


You mistakenly assume that the trigger will react to the change of Password.Length. If you look at the documentation for PasswordBox, it is stated there that this property does not have a notification of its change. Therefore, binding the trigger to it does not make sense. There are several options for solving your problem, but unfortunately your topic was closed - here the moderators compete who will close more topics. Therefore, I cannot give an example of implementation in this topic.

You got it my problem, but the question is marked as duplicate is implementing a code-behind implementation, but I am a newbie in WPF and don't know how I can implement on XAML code. The Password.Length should work, as it is just an integer same as the Text.Length of TextBox control.

In WPF there is no ready-made way to implement ONLY in XAML.
In the duplicate topic there is an answer with the PasswordBoxMonitor class. This class does not belong to Code Behinde. This class is for creating Attached Properties: IsMonitoring and PasswordLength. How to use these Attached Properties in XAML - there is an example in the answer.

@EldHasp yeah that "duplicate" really doesn't answer the question at all. I voted to reopen. You can too, then only 1 more is needed. I also have a solution I can provide if you don't. And Clemens isn't a moderator, just a high rep user who does maybe 90% of the WPF closings.

@EmperorEto I've cast my vote. Now just need to find one more.

@SoftSol Another implementation suggestion. I have very rarely seen PasswordBox used correctly from a security point of view. In practice, 99.9% of its uses are not secure password entry, but simply masking it in the GUI. Outside the GUI, password handling is done in string format, which completely destroys the concept and purpose of PasswordBox and SecurityString. If you just need masking in the GUI, then using TextBox with a masking font will be much more effective and simpler.

@EmperorEto thanks for your support to reopen my question! I really need this solution but now it looks like not possible on this duplicate thread :(

@EldHasp I will try your suggestion TextBox with a masking font. From security PoV, WPF is a windows application that is hard to breach password from my application. In other case they should allow Triggers on Password.Length that's not a big deal!

If they reopen my question, I will put a bounty on it for getting any possible solutions!

@SoftSol oh you're welcome but really don't use your rep points on that. The answer is pretty straightforward. The "duplicate" has the right approach using an attached property but it would be much easier to show the full solution here.

@SoftSol If you are not afraid of the Russian language, you can look at my example of solving TextBox with a masking font at this link: https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2900809.html
You can ask questions directly in that topic in English or Russian.

@EldHasp thanks for your TextBox solution. I will try that.
